# How to fetch third-party data within Twilio interactive voice system?

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

Twilio provides [some documentation](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115016033848-Create-an-IVR-or-Phone-Tree-Menu-with-Twilio-Studio) that explains how to create interactive voice experiences, for example, how to prompt for key-press from the caller and offer different menus or perform actions based on it.

However I cannot find any information on how I might be able to fetch data from a third-party service based on user input.

For example, suppose a user enters his zipcode into the keypad, I would like to fetch the weather from a weather API and return it to the user in speech form.

Is this possible? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Very possible. You can take a look at the documentation below but the key widget is the HTTP Request Widget.

Studio Widget Library

https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library#http-request

The relevant line is:
"JSON: If your HTTP Widget returns valid JSON, you should be able to access it via widgets.MY_WIDGET_NAME.parsed" variable.

Studio User Guide - Working with Variables

https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide#working-with-variables